# "can optionally be" vs. "can be optionally"

Tags: meaning, difference, expressions

"can optionally be" and "can be optionally" - is there any difference in their meaning or tone?

This might look as I haven't tried to find the answer myself, but Google doesn't provide any related questions/answers, and I see both of them in technical publications and books.

I don't know why, but "can optionally be" sounds much better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can optionally be" and "can be optionally"

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position) explains adverb positioning.

> We can put adverbs and adverb phrases at the front, in the middle or at the end of a clause.
>
> Where there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb:

> The government has occasionally been forced to change its mind. (after the first auxiliary verb)

> You can definitely never predict what will happen. (after a modal verb)

> We mightn’t **ever** have met. (**after the modal verb and before the auxiliary verb** [emphasis added])

The 3rd example is similar to OP's question, which involves a modal verb-auxiliary verb combination.

"can optionally be" is hence my suggestion.

Edit after comments from @MarcinManhattan

If *be* is a main verb, the adverb follows the modal verb but precedes the main verb, as described in the 2nd example above.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be) gives another example, now involving the use of *be* as a main verb.

> be verb (EXIST) [ I ] to exist or live: formal Such terrible suffering **should never be** [emphasis added].

I cannot think of an example with this meaning, **exist**, in a phrase *can optionally be*.

Comment: There is no indication in OP's question that "be" is an auxiliary verb. It might be a main verb.

Comment: Thanks, though the logic behind this is still unclear to me...